# How to make a simple GUI for inputting a single variable in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, variables

I have 1 variable in my entire script that I would like to be able to have a GUI to input the information each time the script is ran. I just started learning Python last week, and have no idea. Basically

variable1 = "x"

I would need a GUI to enter what x is each time the script is ran.

Sorry, I know this question is the simplest thing, I'm just lost.

Also, I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Take a look at [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import wx
a =wx.App()
x = wx.GetTextFromUser("Enter X:")
```

is one way to do it that is pretty easy

are you sure

```
x = raw_input("Enter X:")
```

isnt good enough?